# OpenVPN Amazon EC2 VPC to VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, openvpn, amazon-vpc, vpc

I have followed these instructions:
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/0639686206802544

I can ping the VPN endpoints and I have the corresponding VPC CIDR pointing to the EC2 instance in the route table.  Here is my config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

# Remote peer and network
remote Elastic_IP

# Configure local and remote VPN endpoints
ifconfig 169.254.255.1 169.254.255.2

# The pre-shared static key
secret /etc/openvpn/ovpn.key

keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

I can ping the OpenVPN instances and the corresponding endpoints however I still can't ping other private IP's in the other subnet.

I've added a persistent route to send the traffic through the gateway.  Anything else I should look at?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the `Source/dest checks` turned off in the ENI for your VPN instance.